# Starting to work in processing and string doesn't compare

Tags: java, processing

I have the following code:

```
String myString = port.readStringUntil(linefeed);

  if (myString != null) {
    print(myString);
    if (myString.equals("SndEprom")) {
      sending = true;
      print("sending set true");
    }
```

When the code runs this is what log shows:

```
SndEprom
0,255
1,255
2,255
3,255
4,255
5,255
6,255
....
```

I would have thought that the line

> print ("sending set true");

would have run.  What have I done wrong?

Thanks,

Loren

Code for the arduino sending the eeprom data:

In the main loop:

```
if (strcmp(inData, "read")  == 0){
  Serial.println("SndEprom");
  delay(50);
  sendProm();
}

void sendProm(){
  for (int i=0; i <= 100; i++){
    // read a byte from the current address of the EEPROM
    value = EEPROM.read(address);

    Serial.print(address);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(value, DEC);
    Serial.println();

    // advance to the next address of the EEPROM
    address = address + 1;

    // there are only 512 bytes of EEPROM, from 0 to 511, so if we're
    // on address 512, wrap around to address 0


    delay(15);
  } 
  address = 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `myString` is equal to `"SndEprom"`? Check if it has trailing spaces.

Comment: try myString.trim().equals("SndEprom")

Comment: check what exactly `myString` is with something like `print("[" + myString + "]")`

Comment: @wolfrevo when I tried your suggestion this is what I get:  '[SndEprom
][0,255
][1,255'but there is a new line between m and the ]  I've tried changing the firmware on my arduino.  I'll post that code above.

Answer (score 1):

As you said in the comments - the string you actually get is "SndEprom " - note the space at the end.

To resolve the problem use:

```
myString.trim().equals("SndEprom")
```

Comment: @petrosKoutsolampros I don't why he edited that comment, I am pretty sure it said `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`